# window.location.href not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Why won't this work in Safari?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function changeUrl(url) {
  window.location.href='http://google.com';
  return false;
}
</script>

<form action="#" onsubmit="changeUrl(this)" />
  <input type="Submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Safari appears to dislike having the return false occur in the function call.  If you move it into your onsubmit as onsubmit="openPop(this.action);return false;" then Safari will work without issue.

Edit: To improve the answer, onsubmit itself needs to return false, so openPop returning false is not enough.  You could just have it do onsubmit="return openPop(this.action);" though.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work:

```
<script>
function popitup(url) {
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name','height=200,width=150');
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
    return false;
}

// -->
</script>
```

Then use this HTML:

```
<a href="popupex.html" onclick="return popitup('popupex.html')">Link to popup</a>
```

Comment: And of course you could just have it run "onload" instead of "onclick".

Comment: my method name was misleading, i'm not trying to open a new window, just go to a new url

Answer (score -3):

I was able to get it to work in Safari using this code.

```
if (app.Name == "Safari") {
window.location ="your-url-here"
}
```