# What’s the difference between <a href="url"> and window.location = "url" on iOS?

Tags: jquery, ios, html, browser

I have an HTML 5 app that runs on mobile devices including the iPad.  I want to create a link to a non-HTML file, and have the proper application open to handle the file.  The files are .acsm files, to be opened in Bluefire.

If I create the link as a simple `<a href="url">` tag, it works.

If instead I use Javascript to set the `window.location`, it doesn't work.  The iPad pops an alert that says, "Download failed: This file cannot be downloaded".

I've experimented with other file types, and haven't found anything conclusive.  What's the difference between the simple link and the Javascript technique?  Can I make the Javascript code do the same thing as the link?

In case the specific Javascript details matter, I do it like this with jQuery:

```
$('.native-launch').live('click', function (evobj) {
  var there = $(evobj.target).attr('href');
  window.location.href = there;
  return false;
});
```

and the HTML looks like:

```
<span class="catalog-list-button native-launch" href="url">Read in another app</span>
```

(Note that this is a span with an href, I can change the HTML if that would help.)

Comment: Have you tried using `window.open`?

Comment: @kei: great idea!  Doesn't work. :(  It does the same as the Javascript code: "Download failed"

Comment: What if you made an iFrame that loaded the URL? `<iframe src="url"></iframe>`

Comment: I found this. Maybe is your same issue.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210995/window-location-href-not-working-in-safari

Comment: @Jose Faeti: Any idea how to apply the "no return false" to jQuery code that needs it to prevent bubbling up?

Comment: evobj.stopPropagation() will stop it from bubbling up. http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Comment: Did you dump `there` variable inside your callback? Try to use `window.location.assign(there);` or even `setTimeout(function(){window.location.assign(there);}, 50);`

Comment: I have tried all of these suggestions.. :-(

Answer (score 6):

Try `window.open`, passing in "_self" as the target window name.

```
window.open(there, "_self");
```

Using "_self" is the critical part here, otherwise the popup blocker would intercept it.  I'd test this, but I don't have a link to an acsm file.

**Edit:** Two more ideas:

Add a form to your page with a method of "GET" and an action of your acsm file. Exclude form fields unless they map appropriately to your URL.

```
<form id="acsm" method="GET" action="http://myserver.com/myfile.acsm"></form>
```

Then just submit your form with `form.submit()`:

```
document.forms.acsm.submit();
```

And the other idea: Create a page on your server that does a server-side redirect to your acsm file. Then just use the usual `location.href = url` to that server page.

Comment: An interesting idea, it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: Oh, well. It was worth a shot.

Comment: These are more good ideas.  I don't know if they work yet, but they seem promising.

Answer (score 4):

create a new a tag and click it using jquery:

```
$("<a />").attr("href", there).click();
```

the a tag in this case will not be added to DOM, will only be used to simulate the click.

Comment: Hmm, interesting idea.  When I try this, it looks like the click event bubbles up through a number of other divs, triggering events along the way?

Comment: yes, i have made a mistake.
before there was $("a") that would select all the links on the page an click them.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a Safari bug to me.
If you write window.location : Safari is expecting an html file or any type of file it can actualy display.

Whereas when you click a link it reads the content-type and then decide to open it in the same window or open an application for it.

I think you should try to open a popup window with the url. It should theoretically work.

Comment: If by "popup window" you mean window.open, I just tried it and it doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

With the JS-function `window.location` the browser want to open the file with the Browser and not with any other program. But with the A-Tag you link to something. This can be any file. If the browser didn't know the typ of the file the browser alert a popup for download the file. If the file is for example a HTML-File the browser open the file and show it.

For downloading a File with JS here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/349067/download-a-file-using-javascript).

Answer (score 0):

I would think a link was better in case some type of screen reader was trying to parse your page.  If your navigation was in javascript, something like that would fail to tell visually impaired users what's going on.

Btw, instead of `return false;` from your event handler. do `evobj.preventDefault()`, it's the preferred way to stop bubbling for the event.

Comment: thanks for the tip about preventDefault, but if I put that in and remove my "return false", the behavior changes, it looks like the event keeps bubbling to the outer enclosing div.

Comment: If you're handling it from other higher level elements, you can use `event.isDefaultPrevented()` to check whether you should act on it.  Doesn't sound like it in your case though...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-span-element), span element can have only the [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#global-attributes), which doesn't include *href*. So the value fetched from the attribute may be malformed or incompatible with the type accepted by *window.location.href*. I'm not sure if this could be related to the issue.

Did you try assigning a constant string like `window.location.href = "http://example.com/file"`?

Answer (score 0):

If this is a bug with iOS, simulate a click on a link. Unlike memical's solution, this will not bubble:

```
var a = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "a");
a.href = your_url_here;
var click = document.createEvent("Event");
click.initEvent("click", false /*bubbles*/, true /*cancellable*/);
a.dispatchEvent(click);
```