# window.parent.location.href is not working on safari on mac os

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple javascript function. I usually used this javascript code to redirect on other page. I have a modal pop up with link on it. When I click on the link, the whole page will reload and it will redirect to its corresponding page.

```
window.parent.location.href = "url";
```

This code works on all browsers except safari on mac OS. Is there any javascript restrictions on mac os? Please advice.

Comment: Did you got anything in console Or Checked JS is enabled ? @Jarich

Comment: try this: window.parent.location.replace(url)

Comment: Check this lik :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210995/window-location-href-not-working-in-safari

Answer (score 2):

You should be using [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) property:

```
window.opener.location.href = "url";
```

I just verified it and it works fine on Safari 8.0.8 on Yosemite. It also works in other browsers, fortunately. Using [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent) wouldn't indeed work in Safari while working in other browsers.

**Edit:** You can grab the code I used to test it [from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/kamituel/a15411d5536cfe04156a).

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
window.parent.location.assign("url")
```