# Reload window with new url on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a anchro tag with 2 urls. One is href and other is data-url. When i click on button it should open a page in new tab which is correct. But additionally what i want is to reload the current page with the data-url link that i set.

So in the example i set href to google.com and it opens in new tab. Its correct but when we click the button i additionally the the current page to reload to data-url that is youtube.com.

HTML

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" data-url="https://www.youtube.com/" id="agree">Click me</a>
```

JS

```
 $('#agree').on('click', function(e) {
  var url = $(this).data('url');
  console.log(url);
  // window.open(url);
  location.reload(url);
});
```

[Link To Codepen](http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/AXwjEO?editors=1010)

Answer (score 3):

Set the URL to `window.location.href`.

```
$('#agree').on('click', function(e) {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: thanks work . ! 
A quick question thou . what is difference between window.location.href and location.href

Comment: Basically it is the same. But if you somewhere use something like `var location = 'foo';` your script will fail. It is saver to access window properties with `window.` in front. @BipuBajgai

Comment: http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/ZOkmKw  - hey but this doesnot works on mac safari . you know why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210995/window-location-href-not-working-in-safari @BipuBajgai

Comment: i cannot add an onsubmit action to my button thou.

Answer (score 0):

Change location.reload(url) to **location.href = url;**. It will work

Comment: http://codepen.io/sabipu/pen/ZOkmKw - het but this deosnot works on mac safari . you know why ?